# What are the various supernatural entities mentioned in scriptures (like Vedas, Puranas etc.)?

Tags: scripture, supernatural-races

People often believe one or more supernatural beings such as *bhut*, *preta* or *pisach*. I would like to know **about all the Supernatural entities, from all the major canonical texts (Vedas, Puranas, Shastras, Itihasasas, etc.)**? (With a short description of what they are.)

---

Please note that:

1. I am not asking about the various divine beings or ascended masters. This is regardless of whether they can be considered as having supernatural powers . Thus, devatas or avatars are not included. Nether are rishis or other siddha humans who gained powers through tapas etc.
2. I am asking about the types or categories of supernatural beings, not individual examples. For example, Ravan, Kumbhakaran and Suparnkha are all included in Raskshasas, so they are not separate supernatural entities for the purposes of this question.
3. Asuaras, apsaras, yaskahas etc are included. If there are some major sub-types to any, the information would be a plus.
4. I realize that different scriptures could accept different categories to this answer. However, they can still be listen as combination in one answer, or as different answers.

---

### Edit:

The related question [What are the different types of supernatural creatures/beings according to vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44447/what-are-the-different-types-of-supernatural-creatures-beings-according-to-vedas) has a similar title. But it is asking for a different thing than this one.

The linked question specifically asks for creatures mentioned from the Vedas. I am asking for all categories of beings including Ithihasa, Purana with brief explanation of what they are. The last thing is significant because many of these beings seem very similar to each other when one does not know the details. So, what they are is an important thing different from simply their names. They are two different things.

So, this should not be a duplicate.

Comment: [List of legendary creatures in Hindu mythology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_legendary_creatures_in_Hindu_mythology)

Comment: Hello Devashish, are you happy with the closure of your question as a duplicate? You can post a comment here stating whether you're happy or not.

Comment: How it got closed with just 2 votes..is it bcz u hv tag badge? @Rickross

Comment: Yes, because I have a scripture gold badge, and that's why I'm worried whether it's closed unfairly or not :( @YDS

Comment: @Rickross No, I think this is not a duplicate. The linked question specifically asks for creatures mentioned from the Vedas. I am asking for all categories of beings including Ithihasa, Purana with brief explanation of what they are. They are two different things.

Comment: Okay. I have voted to reopen and it is now open. @DevashsihKaushik Let now others decide if it's a duplicate or not.

Comment: Your question is toooo broad. Needs more focus.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Is it really? While the number of potential entries in the question is admittedly a bit large, I think the scope of the question itself is quite clear. The question itself is objective enough, IMHO. Couldn't this be useful?

Comment: I second Swamiji.The answer to your question is going to be longer than whatever time the patience of most reader can....